# What is a neuron bank?

Tags: machine-learning, terminology, dropout

In the [Dropout paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1207.0580.pdf) they refer to neuron banks on page 15:

> ... the
>   activity a^i
>   (x,y) of a neuron in bank i at position (x, y) in the topographic organization ...

What is a neuron bank?

Context:
[image]

Comment: crossposted on https://redd.it/5tnyr8

Comment: cross-posted on CS.SE: http://cs.stackexchange.com/q/70226/755.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068). Each community should have an honest shot at answering without anybody's time being wasted.

Comment: @D.W. Affirmative, sorry about that. Won't happen again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

bank = array or set. The term comes from the [signal processing terminology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filter_bank).

A hint from the paper you mention:

> In this way, a bank of neurons
>   in a CNN applies a convolution operation to its input. A single layer in a CNN typically has
>   multiple banks of neurons, each performing a convolution with a different filter. These banks of
>   neurons become distinct input channels into the next layer.

The parameter of each neuron  bank in a convolutional layer is called a  *filter bank* or just filter (a.k.a. kernel a.k.a. feature detector).

For example, using this illustration from [Stanford's deep learning tutorial](http://deeplearning.stanford.edu/wiki/index.php/Feature_extraction_using_convolution):

[image]

The filter bank is the yellow sliding window, and its value is:

\begin{bmatrix}
    1      & 0 & 1  \\
    0      & 1 & 0  \\
    1      & 0 & 1  
\end{bmatrix}

The green array is the input to one neuron bank, and the pink array is the output of one neuron bank.

I don't think the term  neuron bank is commonly used nowadays.

(That's a lot of confusing terms for a simple mathematical operation… )

Comment: Ok, so from my understanding, each [output] neuron bank is associated with a different filter. So in this context we are comparing a collection of output neuron banks and each of their neurons must complete against neurons in the same x,y coordinate on other output neuron banks. So all neurons with in the same [output] neuron bank have the same `z` coordinate.